# Include library from CDN and local browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

If loading jQuery from CDN with ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/...
```

... then it will *not* be accepted if the website is HTTPS (`Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/...`).

---

The solution seems to be :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/...
```

Indeeed it will work if the website is HTTP or HTTPS. **But when working on the file locally** (i.e. browse the file on my hard drive), then jQuery is not loaded with this solution.

---

*This is important for me, that people who will download [my GitHub project](https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/) will be able to test it locally.*

**How to include jQuery properly with CDN, and be able to browse locally the HTML file?**

Comment: It's very simple to set up a local webserver for testing purposes. Do that instead.

Comment: @Tomalak no, having to install a webserver for testing a simple .js + .html page is an overkill. I use Windows and don't have a local webserver for testing client-side libraries. If I really need a server, yes, I connect another machine, etc. but I don't like the idea of needing a webserver for two simple files (.html + .js)

Comment: If you have Windows then you have the IIS pre-installed, you just need to enable it from the Windows feature list. That's a 5-click-operation and you are up and running in a couple of minutes. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: I can't ask every person who will try a basic 1 HTML page + 1 JS file to enable a webserver

Comment: You make it sound as if it was horribly complicated. It's a few clicks and you're done. It would have taken you a *tiny fraction* of the 2 hours this question is now old. And seriously, if you want your files to work from a web server, let them run on a web server, everything else is nonsense.

Comment: I really don't agree @Tomalak. It's not about me: if I host two small files on github, I can't ask every person who will want to test them (in this project, nothing is done on server side) to run a webserver.

Comment: Huh? If you host files on GitHub, then [*that's* your webserver](https://pages.github.com/). Or maybe use DropBox. There are a ton of freely available possibilities. Why would you want to let anyone download those files and run them locally?

Comment: Never mind. I mean: In general, requiring a webserver to run just a simple HTML page is bad (for me).

Answer (score 2):

In general, testing web pages using `file://` URLs is a bad idea and I wouldn't bother to support it. Instead, testing with a local webserver makes more sense.

But if you're intent on supporting it, you'll need to do a check on `location.protocol`:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var protocol = location.protocol === "file:" ? "http:" : location.protocol;
    document.write('<script src="' + protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
})();
</script>
```

Or if you're doing an XHTML page (or just don't like `document.write`):

```
<script>
(function() {
    var protocol = location.protocol === "file:" ? "http:" : location.protocol;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
})();
</script>
```

That uses the protocol of the page (`http:`, `https:`, whatever) if it's not `file:`, and uses `http:` if it's `file:`.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder for your answer. Can I also use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/...` all the time? it seems to work 1) from local browsing (`file://`),  2) from a http website,  3) from a https website.

Comment: @Basj: In general, the advice is to match the protocol of the page where possible (hence the popularity of protocol-relative URLs). But since you can't do that with the `file:` protocol, you have to play a game like the one above.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458680/1422096 (I'm not sure, would be happy to have your advice)

Comment: @Basj: I can't immediately think of why it would be a problem to use an `https` JavaScript link on an `http` page, so go for it if you like. Note: `type` defaults to `text/javascript`, so there's no reason to put `type` on the `script `tag.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with HTTPS all the time :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/...
```

It seems to work :

1. from local browsing of the HTML page (`file://`)
2. from http browsing of the HTML page
3. from https browsing of the HTML page

Answer (score -1):

From HTML5 Boilerplate, add after your CDN script:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/path/to/local/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```